# Was Senator Armstrong's plan intended to work?

Tags: metal-gear-solid, metal-gear-rising

So, obviously his plan wouldn't have worked in "real life." Most succinctly, it's a clear example of the [Broken Window Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_broken_window). Dozens of arguments exist for why it would be a bad idea, fine, I accept that.

What I haven't seen argued or examined is whether Armstrong's plan was intended by the developers or writers to work. Keeping in mind Metal Gear's universe and its politics act differently from ours. Also keeping in mind that whether Armstrong was actually right has major impacts on Raiden's character development and the stinger at the end of the game.

My question is: is there any word from developers on whether Armstrong was intended to be correct? Specifically, that he could have ended the Patriots' wars if he had become president instead of being cut down by Raiden?

Comment: It would be good to at least briefly summarize what "Senator Armstrong's Plan" was, in spoiler tags, in the question, so that those of us who haven't played the game can follow along. As it stands, this question and its answers are gibberish to me, they're discussing the merits of something without describing what it is. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it gets really complicated, because MGS is based around realistic fiction. I would have to say it would work in their universe, but a lot of people would have died from the "war on terror" and a lot of orphaned children will be harvested for their brains and turned into emotionless cyborg soldiers.
Raiden didn't like this and decided to kill Armstrong because he knew he wouldn't be able to convince him to stop, plus he hates politicians. It would have worked in their universe because the USA is a war economy, they thrive off of war, which was something the patriots ensured would happen. Armstrong wanted
to completely cut out the patriots influence, so he would use one last war to get elected and as president, end war as a business. His intentions during his presidency however would destroy the government and reduce America to a Mad Max-esque wasteland, where everyone fights for their own reasons on their own, stamping out anyone weak in will and strength as a result.

Comment: Hey, it looks like you intended to update your answer. If possible, you should register your account and then [contact Stack Overflow about merging them together](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: You should really be editing this into your previous answer not adding a new one. You can merge your accounts by following the link [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)